# Trouble with drawing Bezier curve in Python

Tags: python, bezier

Hi people i need some help.I wrote a code in Python (Tkinter) that is drawing a 3 degree Bezier curve,and it works...kinda.My problems are:How can i directly input from keybord x and y coordinates for control points,and not first x then y (like in my code).Second issue is regarding parametar (u or t) value.Usually it is normalised (value 0 to 1) but for loop wouldnt work with decimal values for steps (i know its obvious :)).If i put u=1->1000 and then divide value by 1000 it is numericaly unstable.Third and least important is how to draw curve,you will se that I used small lines which is really stupid but dont know other way here is my code,sorry its in Word format,had some troubles:

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import*

master=Tk()

w=Canvas(master,width=800,height=800)


w.pack()

def kriva():

        P0=[]
        P1=[]
        P2=[]
        P3=[]
        P0.append (float(input(" x for P0")))  #HERE IS THE PLACE FOR INPUT COORDINATES OF CONTROL POINTS
        P0.append (float(input(" y for P0")))
        P1.append(float(input(" x for P1")))
        P1.append(float(input(" yfor P1")))    
        P2.append(float(input(" x for za P2")))
        P2.append(float(input(" y for za P2")))

        P3.append(float(input(" x for P3")))
        P3.append(float(input(" y for P3")))


        for u  in range (0,1000,1):
            u=(u/1000) # PARAMETAR FOR CURVE
               x=(P0[0]*(1-u)**3+P1[0]*3*u*(1-u)**2+P2[0]*3*u**2*(1-u)+P3[0])*u**3#BERNSTAIN    POLYNOMS FOR X AND Y         
               y=(P0[1]*(1-u)**3+P1[1]*3*u*(1-u)**2+P2[1]*3*u**2*(1-u)+P3[1]*u**3)
            x1=x+1 #THIS IS END OF THE LINE
            y1=y+1
            print (x)
            print (y)
            w.create_line(x,y,x1,y1) #IM DOOING THIS THIS WAY BECAUSE I DONT KNOW ANY OTHER    WAY TO DRAW CURVE :)

kriva()
mainloop()
```

Fixed all issues..here is the final code...special thanks for help

import tkinter

from tkinter import*

master=Tk()

w=Canvas(master,width=800,height=800)

w.pack()

def kriva():

```
P0=[]

P1=[]

P2=[]

P3=[]

#p0:

unosp0=input("unesi koordinate za P0")

koordinatep0=unosp0.split(',')

print (koordinatep0)

P0.append(float((koordinatep0[0])))

P0.append(float((koordinatep0[1])))

print (P0)

#p1:

unosp1=input("unesi koordinate za P1")

koordinatep1=unosp1.split(',')

print (koordinatep1)

P1.append(float((koordinatep1[0])))

P1.append(float((koordinatep1[1])))

print (P1)

#p2:

unosp2=input("unesi koordinate za P2")

koordinatep2=unosp2.split(',')

print (koordinatep2)

P2.append(float((koordinatep2[0])))

P2.append(float((koordinatep2[1])))

print (P2)

#p3:

unosp3=input("unesi koordinate za P3")

koordinatep3=unosp3.split(',')

print (koordinatep3)

P3.append(float((koordinatep3[0])))

P3.append(float((koordinatep3[1])))

print (P3)

x1=P0[0]

y1=P0[1]

for u  in range (0,1001,1):

    u=(u/1000)

    x=(P0[0]*(1-u)**3+P1[0]*3*u*(1-u)**2+P2[0]*3*u**2*(1-u)+P3[0]*u**3)

    y=(P0[1]*(1-u)**3+P1[1]*3*u*(1-u)**2+P2[1]*3*u**2*(1-u)+P3[1]*u**3)
```

### print (x)

### print (y)

### print (x1)

### print(y1)

### x1=str(x+000001)

### y1=str(x+0,00001)

```
    linija=w.create_line(x,y,x1,y1)

    x1=x

    y1=y
```

kriva()

mainloop()

Comment: Nothing stupid about drawing a curve by drawing many small lines. That's pretty much the best way to do it.

Comment: Sundar,im not sure which errors...i have tried running script and it works...no errors reported.Thanks anyway

Comment: Kevin do you maybe know any other way i could do it?At least with points,if not by smooth curve?

Comment: _"i have tried running script and it works"_. Do you mean, you have copy-pasted the exact code you wrote here, and ran it, and it works? Or do you mean, the code that you originally transcribed this code from works? Because the latter doesn't rule out the possibility that you mistyped when making this question.

Comment: _"At least with points,if not by smooth curve?"_ I don't know what you mean by that. Lines _are_ made out of points.

Comment: Kevin,sorry,i think i found some problems with brackets,if thats everything when it comes to errors...hope its fine now,thanks...when i said "points" i meant points with gaps.Mathematicaly speaking you are right but i meant is there a way to make curve as sequence of dots (points) like you could i AutoCad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get both X and Y coordinates from the same input, you'll just have to decide on a simple syntax and parse it. For instance, you can say that X and Y will be entered in that order, separated by a comma, and then do something like this

```
inp = input('Enter X,Y coordinates:')
parts = inp.split(',')
if len(parts) != 2:
    raise ValueErrror("You entered the wrong number of coordinates!")
x = float(parts[0].strip())
y = float(parts[1].strip())
```

Or much more compactly (but without the error handling):

```
x, y = (float(p.strip()) for p in input('Enter X,Y coordinates:').split(','))
```

For iterating over a floats, your idea to divide by 1000 is fine. What do you mean its numerically unstable? I would do it exactly like this:

```
num_of_points = 1000
for i in xrange(num_of_points+1):
    u = float(i) / float(num_of_points)
```

Notice I set the range to `num_of_points+1`, so that `num_of_points` will actually be included: that means the loop will actually go from 0 to 1.0, inclusive.

Drawing a line between the points is probably the correct answer. Yes, it is an approximation, but it's limited only by the resolution of the image and the number of points you want to draw. If you want a more accurate depiction, just iterate over a larger `num_of_points`.

To do anything more accurate than a line, you would need to figure out some approximation of what the curve looks like in between those two points. But that's exactly what your script is doing, it's approximating a Bezier. So you could recursively approximate the curve between every pair of points you find, but that's the same as just adding more points to your approximation.

That said, the specific way in which you're drawing lines is baffling me. As far as I can tell, you're calculating a point `(x,y)` on the curve (more specifically `(x(u), y(u))` for parameter `u`), and then drawing a line from that point to a point at `(x+1, y+1)`. In other words, you're always just drawing a little 45-degree "tick" off of the point on the curve. Not really sure why, unless you wanted to just make a little mark and weren't sure how to just fill in a single pixel.

Whatever the reason, the correct way to do it is to determine two "adjacent" points on the curve, and *connect them* with a line. Something like:

```
last_point = calculate_point_on_curve(u=0)
for i in xrange(1, num_of_points+1):
    x, y = calculate_point_on_curve( float(i) / float(num_of_points) )
    last_x, last_y = last_point
    w.create_line(last_x, last_y, x, y)
    last_point = (x, y)
```

Here the actual parametric equation for calculating the points on the line is hidden inside the `calculate_point_on_curve` function, just to simplify the code snippet.

To deal with your apparent decimation issue, try this:

```
u = 0.0
for t in xrange(10001):
    calculate_point_on_curve(u)
    u = u + 0.0001
```

Comment: sh 1ftst0rm...thank you very much... inp.split was the thing i was looking for but couldnt find,now i get it.When it comes to numerical unstability,when you run code you can see that as the values for u are bigger especially between p2 and p3 gaps between lines are bigger.That logical since approximation of u/1000 is less and less equal to the one one when u is 0->1...any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you mean. Yes, floating point numbers can only approximate most values, but I don't see what you mean about them getting progressively worse. For instance, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1.0 can all be exactly represented in floating point, as can lots of other values. So 500.0/1000.0 should be exact, as should 125.0/1000.0, etc.

Comment: To be honest I didn't look that hard at your code before answering, but I just noticed the _way_ in which you're drawing lines: why are you always drawing a line to `(+1,+1)` from the point on the curve? You should be drawing it from one point on the curve to the next point on the curve.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a better description of how to draw the lines as suggested in my last comment.

Comment: Ok,thanks again...ill now try to figure it out.....I tried to solve coordinates issue like you told me,but python keeps telling me that he doesnt know what "strip" is and neither do I :) can you please help me with just this one?

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, it should be a method invoked on the strings, not a stand alone function, i.e., it should be `p.strip()`. I've updated the answer to correct this. All it does is remove leading and trailing whitespace from a string, so if you entered your coordinates as, say `19 , 23`, it will work correctly (you'll end up with `'19'` and `'23'`, instead of `'19 '` and `' 23'`).

Comment: Oh,ok...you are speaking to a python dummy just so you know :)....I was just looking at your update for end of the line coordinates,and correct me if im wrong but its a constant point (acctualy its start point with u=0 not end,but that not important),and i am connecting all points of the curve with that one,and i will get something like a fan.Also that doesnt really solves problem,cause in my code there was a problem starting points are progresivly furter from eachother. :(

Comment: No, notice the last line of the `for` loop: you're updating `last_point` so that it is always the coordinates of the last point on the curve that you calculated. So for instance, if `num_points` was 4, you would calculate four points, which we could call p0, p1, p2, and p3. What you want to do (and what the code I provided does) is draw a line from p0 to p1, then from p1 to p2, then from p2 to p3. Its not a fan, its your Bezier curve, except with segments of the curve approximated by line segments instead of smooth curves.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean about "points are progressively further from eachother"? If your equations for the Bezier curve are correct (which I haven't attempted to verify, I'm not familiar with that form of a Bezier), then each point should be a point on the curve. Beziers are a little unpredictable in how a small step in the parameter will effect the point, so it is possible depending on the curve that points get further and further apart the further you go along the curve. But all the points should be sequential on the curve as `u` increases.

Comment: My bad...i see it now.....this was really huge help help for me.....hope thats all

Comment: This form of calculation are Bernstain polynoms they should be far less prone to errors than Horners algorithm....i am not sure also why thsis is happening my best guess is because variable is not normalised,and that it messes up with bigger numbers....if you have spare time try running my code with points set so you can get something like parabolycal arc,and you will see visually...

Comment: Update regarding normalised variables:Found a way not to use for loops for parameter,but simple function instead that keeps callint it self.Its dooing somethings with decimals which are not clear to me,but im working on it.Anyway I think you could,and since you are answering and helping many people i taught you should know.Here it is:

Comment: import sys
def b(u):
    
    if u>=0 and u<=1:
        print(u)
        b(u+0.0001)   
    else:
        sys.exit(0)
    
b(0)

Comment: The technique of having a function call itself is called _recursion_, and it can be a very useful technique. But un thus case i don't see anynreason to use it over a simple for loop. A for loop has a lot less memory and processor overhead than recursion, and recursion has a limited depth. The particular code you give is particularly poor: its bad python code in general, and specifically it would be much simpler, faster, and more intuitive to do with a for loop. All it's doing is incrementing by one ten-thousandth ar=t a time, no reason not to do that with a for or while loop.

Comment: I guess your right...what you should know is that im still in (early) learning stage and that im experimenting with different things.....what i like bout this code is that i can go from 0 to 1 without any division...Further more my final goal are complex computation with NURBS surfaces,and i think that would take too many for loops, and kill my memory....so this was just one of the experiments...thanks again for help and oppinion

Comment: I understand you're new to programming, that's why I'm trying to help you understand that this is an inappropriate use of revision. For loops don't take any extra memory, just one variable to store the current value and one variable to store the sequence of values to loop over. If you're worried about memory, in Python you can use `xrange` instead of `range` then it wont have to store all loop values at once, it will generate them one at a time. Recursion on the other hand will add memory usage for every call/iteration.

Comment: Also, you're too early in programming to be worrying about optimizing like this. You don't know enough about what is happening behind the scenes to be able to do it effectively and you're more likely to waste resources than save them. Rest assured that a modern PC has ample speed and memory for most of what you'll be doing in python. Besides that if you're really worried about efficiency, you should be writing compiled code like C, but that's probably not necessary for you.

Comment: I really cant thank you enough for your help.....im interested in attending PhD studies in optimization of NURBS surfaces according to demands of finite element method (statical analysis) and at the moment your my biggest helper....thanks again